# Add Actions to a list for a later execution

Tags: c#, delegates

Suppose I want to prepare some `List<Action> listOfMethods` 
or better `List<Func> listOfMethods` with their parameters 
for a later execution using  :

```
foreach (var action in listOfMethods)
{
    action.Invoke();                 
}
```

The way below of adding the methods cause an immediate execution which I don't want:

```
listOfMethods.Add(() => processor.DoStuff(m1Parameters));
```

Is there a way to add the method with its parameters without causing immediate execution?

Comment: Are you sure [your 2nd method causes immediate execution](http://ideone.com/8FLNqR)?

Comment: This way can't cause immediate execution. Show us your *real* code.

Comment: The premise of your question appears to be flawed. What you add to your list is perfect for deferred execution and won't cause the lambda bodies to be executed.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a lambda expression like `() => processor.DoStuff(m1Parameters)` the body of the lambda it's not executed.

When you write the line:

```
listOfMethods.Add(() => processor.DoStuff(m1Parameters));
```

The method `DoStuff` it's not executed, but after this block, there may be something that is firing the lambda expression.

Like your block

```
foreach (var action in listOfMethods)
{
    action.Invoke();                 
}
```

Probably at this block the action is being fired.

Comment: Thank you @JonnyPiazzi, I have found my bug ! DoStuff is actually fired elsewhere in the code and the adding **does not** cause immediate execution.